# Flush out all other characters in input buffer

Tags: c++, buffer, program-entry-point

I am trying to control the usage of a small console application, and don't want the user to type anything more than one character. What I have so far

```
int main()
{
   char choice;
   string strChoice;

    /*Set the title bar title to Binary Calculator*/
      system("title Binary Calculator 2014");

    do{
      Menu();
      getline(cin,strChoice);
      choice = toupper(strChoice[0]); //convert value to uppercase for conformity
      DetermineChoice(choice);
   } while (mistakes < 3);
}
```

But when I type

```
bbbbbbbb
```

The screen goes buggy as all hell ( I believe it's caused from the do while loop ) so I need to just flush all characters besides the first one. Also when I select `B` the first time the program runs, then I go back and try to select `B` again it says I don't have anything but a carriage return in the input buffer.

Above is my int main. I'll show you the determine choice function and the error handling function.

```
void DetermineChoice(char value)
{
    /*
        Purpose: Determine what character was passed to value
        Pre: a hopefully valid character
        Post: Will go through cases below and then pass to another function
    */
  string binary;
  int decimal;

  switch (value)
  {
    case 'B': 
    case 'C': 
        ConversionOperation(value);
    case 'P': 
        cout << "Process File" << endl; 
        break;
    case '+':
    case '-':
    case '/':
    case '*':
    case '%': ArithmeticActions(value);
    case 'Q':
        PrintSummary();
        break;
    default: 
        HandleChoiceError(value); 
        break;
  }
}
```

Choice Error:

```
void HandleChoiceError(char value)
{
    /*
       Purpose: Handles the errorenous character passed
       Pre: an invalid character
       Post: Will output the error, pausing the screen then reprint the menu
    */
   system("cls");
   mistakes++;
   cout << setw(40) << "The option you selected (" << value << ") is not a valid choice." << endl;
   cout << setw(25) << "You have made " << mistakes << " mistake" << (mistakes > 1 ? "s" : "") <<" becareful only three allowed!" << endl;
   cout << setw(60) <<  "Please press enter and try again" << endl;
   if (mistakes < 3)
   {
      system("pause");
   }
}
```

Some things that need to be aware of::

I can only use system (so please don't tell me it's bad or resource hog!)

I can't use `fflush` or any flushing besides `cin.clear()`

I can't use any other libraries besides `iostream` , `iomanip` , `fstream` , `string` ,  and `ctype.h`

Thanks everyone I now have the program working correctly.

```
int main()
{
    char choice;
    string strChoice;

    /*Set the title bar title to Binary Calculator*/
    system("title Binary Calculator 2014");

    do{
        Menu();
        if ( getline(cin, strChoice) )
        {
            choice = toupper(strChoice[0]);
            DetermineChoice(choice);
            cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Something went wrong with the input, please restart the program and try again." << endl;
            break;
        }
    } while (mistakes < 3);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `std::getline`, then either detect the multiple chars and spew a single error or process only the first char and ignore the rest.

Comment: doesn't getline have an issue as well?

Comment: What issue would you be referring to? It sucks in everything up to the `'\n'`, discards the `'\n'` and presents you with the line. if the line is longer than a single char you know you have bogus input. if it has one char and it doesn't match your criteria, again, bogus input. If it has one char and it fulfills one of your matches, you're good to go. Maybe you're thinking about something I'm not (not unlikely).

Comment: Ok, yeah I remember the issue is `getline` then using `cin >> choice` or `cin.get`
I need to flush the buffer after a system pause, I believe that is where the conflict is but I am updating my question with your resolution on the first part

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. I'm talking about `std::string line; `std::getline(cin, line);` and using `line`, to craft exactly what I described above. `cin >> choice` and `cin.get()` are *nowhere* in what I described. Your code update seems to reflect that, so what is the problem? The input buffer shouldn't *need* flushing once you do this.

Comment: No i know i was explaining where I came up with the issue getline has. I've had to `cin.clear` when I used the different methods. I've updated with almost exactly as you explained. should I clear in the main do while loop before getting the getline?

Comment: Why should you `clear()` ? you already slurped the entire line and ate the new line, and there is no failed io state unless `std::getline` failed (which you should check, btw).

Comment: I get my program running the first time. Works just like I thought. Then when I press enter after the system pause, which the program then should output the menu once again and ask for another choice. Well instead i press enter and I get an error from `HandleChoiceError` that states this: `( ) is not a valid choice`

Comment: If you start with entering an empty line your code could fail! You need to verify that the input is successful and the read line is non-empty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as "flushing" an `std::istream`. Flushing is an output concept. Since there are multiple buffers for input from the console (the input buffer inside the `std::istream`'s `std::streambuf` and an operating system consolde buffer) there is no reliable way to actually get rid of all input characters. You can get rid of all characters by disabling the concole's buffer (on UNIXes you'd use `tcsetattr()` and `tcgetattr()` to clear the `ICANON` flag).

The approaches which should be good enough for you needs are to either ignore all charactesr on the current line or to remove all characters in the input buffers:

1. To remove all characters on the currently you'd use `std::istream::ignore()` with the maximum number of characters to be ignored and the character where to stop, i.e., `'\n'` for the newline. To match as many characters as needed, you'd pass the magic value `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` (a reasonably large value, say 10000, would do the trick for practical needs, too).
2. You can find out a lower bound of characters immediately available using `in.rdbuf()->in_avail()`. This function determines how many characters can be read without the stream blocking. In practice, this is the number of characters in the `std::istream`'s input buffer, i.e., something like `in.ignore(in.rdbuf()->in_avail())` should remove all characters.

Pesronally, I would go with using `in.ignore(count, '\n')` with a suitable `count` (I'd obviously use `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` but it seems you can't use this function, probably because I'm currently helping with your homework assignment). Of course, `std:getline()` already reads the entire line anyway, i.e., there isn't really anything to be ignored.

Note that you should **always** verify whether the input operation was actuall successful:

```
if (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
    // process successful line
}
else {
    // deal with the input having failed
}
```

Note, that input of a line is successful even when the line is empty! Before accessing the first character you should verify that it is present, e.g., using `!line.empty()`.

BTW, as you have mentioned `clear()`: that actually doesn't ignore any characters. Instead, it clears the stream error flags, i.e., what is being tested to verify if input is successful. While being on notes: the argument to any of the `<cctype>` functions has to be a non-negative `int` in the value range of `unsigned char` plus `EOF`. Since `char` tends to be signed, passing an arbitrary `char`, e.g., `strChoice[0]` can result in undefined beheavior (e.g. when passing an ISO-Latin-1 or UTF-8 representation of my second name). The normal fix is to use

```
std::toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(strChoice[0]))
```

Comment: Thank you for this post, it opened a lot for me. And yes it is a homework assignment, but I NEVER ask for anyone to write anything for me :) I hate that when I see it. I can usually figure out the rest of the code when someone mentions `use this` or whatever. I just never know exactly what to type into google. Thanks Dietmar +1

Comment: @EasyBB: dang! I had hoped for getting the answer accepted without an upvote and get another **hat**! :-) Of course, since I further improved the answer (to point out additional issues) I guess, there is only a slim chance...

Comment: Accepting your answer since WhozCraig hasn't posted an answer, but both of you helped me greatly. And man I forgot about the hats!!!

Comment: @EasyBB Deitmar writes *solid* answers, I've no problem up-ticking this (only because Dietmar already lost his hat to someone else's uptick =P)

Comment: Sorry bout that :/ I always forget the Winterbash

Comment: @EasyBB: no worries - it is just a silly thing ;) I already collected more hats than seems reasonable.

Comment: Yeah I only have one LMAO

Answer (score 2):

Easiest to patch in: Replace

```
cin.ignore(1);
```

with

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

and

```
#include <limits>
```

at the top of the file. What this means is: "ignore all characters in the stream up to the next newline character (`\n`)". This is because

```
cin.ignore(n, c);
```

means "ignore `n` characters from cin, but stop after you found `c`," and `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()` is the largest value in the `streamsize` type and a special case for `istream::ignore` where it means infinity.

This will work nicely for your use case because user input is generally line-based. It is better than discarding the input buffer because what's in the input buffer is not always predictable (someone could pipe a file to your program, the terminal could buffer strangely, the user could be a very fast typist, among other things). Discarding the input buffer wholesale will sometimes yield strange results, but nobody will be terribly surprised if you discard the rest of the line after a command.

Comment: I should have stated can't added any other libraries besides string,iomanip,iostream,fstream, and ctype.

Comment: Then write `streamsize(size_t(-1) / 2)` instead of `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()`. It looks less pretty, but it means the same. `size_t(-1)` is the largest value in `size_t` (because `size_t` is unsigned), and `streamsize` is `size_t`'s signed counterpart, so its max value will be half that.

Comment: Still can't use these either they may be apart of the STL but my professor does not accept functions we haven't learned. Trust me I get points taken off for using ternary's. I am only going to get the degree I don't need college for coding lmao. Though their limitations have made me think outside the box that is for sure. Sorry mate

Comment: Then use 100000 and be done with it. It'll cover all your use cases.

Comment: LOL! Yeah I will try this out, though wouldn't `80` work since that is the size of the console application?

Comment: Someone can hack in more than 80 characters before pressing return. The way your terminal renders it doesn't really matter.